# iOS 6 - Tab Bar controller locked to portrait except when presenting modal MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, orientation, mpmovieplayercontroller, autolayout, portrait

I have an tab bar app that has several views. Each view should be locked to Portrait mode, except when displaying a video in a movieviewcontroller. 
What is the proper way to set this up?

App is for iOS 6.0 and above, and uses autolayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just had to create a category for UITabBarController with these methods:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}
- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

Then in my subclassed MPMoviePlayerViewController:

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder{
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)canResignFirstResponder{
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return true;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Now all the tab views are locked to portrait / upside down portrait while the movie player is free to rotate in any orientation.